# Contact Information pattern detector using naive bayes

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, classification, naivebayes

I am trying to implement Naive Bayes classifier to detect a contact information input by user. The contact information can be

1. A mobile number
2. An email id
3. A web link

So, user inputs a paragraph. It may contain valid data + contact information. My job is to detect the part ( half / full sentence) which contains the contact info and remove it.

For example:

```
I am John. I am new to this site. For more details you may contact me on my mobile number xxxxxxxxx.

I am Rahul. My mobile number is xxxxxxxxx.
```

Till now this job is manually done, so I have a data for more than Millions paragraphs.

Earlier, I implemented a regex based algorithm to achieve the same but that seems very primitive. User inputs different kind of data, which needs to be handled intelligently.

What could be other implementations? Any other ideas?

Comment: naive bayes based solution will be way more primitive then well designed regex.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Any other suggestions?

Comment: You did not specify which language you are using, but what you may be looking for is a grammar, but for something between full grammar parsers and the use of regexes, libs like Parsley (in Python, https://github.com/python-parsley/parsley) may help